# Linq issue not returning students

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, web-services, rest

So I have an windows form application (client) which displays which groups belong to a student.

On the service side this is done like so:

```
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    List<Group> Groups = new List<Group>();
    public List<Group> GetStudentCollectionByGroup(string anything)
    {

        List<Group> groups = (from g in Groups
                              where
                                  (from t in g.Groupsz where
                                          string.Equals(t.StudentID, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                       || string.Equals(t.FirstName, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                       || string.Equals(t.LastName, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                   select t).Count() > 0
                              select g).ToList();
        return groups;
    }
```

To add a student to a group I have used this method:

```
    public void AddStudentToGroup(string group, string studentID, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        var result = Groups.Where(n => String.Equals(n.GroupName, group)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.Groupsz.Add(new Student() { StudentID = studentID });
            result.Groupsz.Add(new Student() { FirstName = firstName });
            result.Groupsz.Add(new Student() { LastName = lastName });
        }
    }
```

And my GET method looks like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/GetStudentCollectionByGroup/{anything}")]
    List<Group> GetStudentCollectionByGroup(string anything);
```

The data contracts look like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        StudentGroup = new List<Group>();
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "StudentID")]
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Group> StudentGroup { get; set; }
}
[DataContract(Name = "Group")]
public class Group
{
    public Group() 
    {
        Groupsz = new List<Student>();
    }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Groupsz { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have no problem getting the group from my client side when I type in the specific student. But when I type into a different textbox to get the students based on Group nothing is returned? For instance if I type **group** "A" it should return all the students who belong to that group. Just like how I return a collection of groups who belong to **student** "B"

Comment: Your code has many problems.  First: use `.Any()` instead of `.Count() > 0`.  That's a performance tip, though, it shouldn't have an effect on the correctness of your code.  Second, your `AddStudentToGroup` method actually adds THREE students to the group: one whose ID is the given ID, and whose first and last names are null; one whose ID and last name are null, and whose first name is the given first name; and one whose ID and first name are null, and whose last name is the given last name.

Comment: Im just hoping that altho I add students to a group I dont have to do it the opposite way around **aswell**?

Comment: Is `Groupsz` an error, or is it a separate collection from `Groups`?

Comment: @phoog o dear at your first comment :(

Comment: Its seperate as I had already used Groups for the list. (See public class Group) and first bit of code for lists.

Comment: Your `GetGroupCollectionByStudent` is a bit confusing since it returns a collection of students, but its name implies that it returns a collection of groups.  Also `from student in students` would be less confusing than `from g in students` -- it's hard work to remember that `g` does *not* refer to a group.  And, again, use `.Any()` rather than `.Count() > 0`.  However, the method appears to be correct.  I don't think your problem lies there.

Comment: The conventional name for a list of students in a group would be `Students`: `class Group { public List<Student> Students { get { ...`

Comment: Ah yeah I guess it does imply that, made sense to me for some reason when I was doing it. Sorry, just glad you still recognise the code and what I am trying to do.

Comment: I mean I know I can fix this by adding another post which adds groups to students aswell as student to groups, was just hoping/wondering why I would have to tho as what I have should still work when I search groups, it should return the students like it does when I search students and it displays groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem, not sure why but adding the student to the group and group to the student seems to work. However I could be duplicating records.

```
  public void AddStudentToGroup(string group, string studentID, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        var result = Groups.Where(n => String.Equals(n.GroupName, group)).FirstOrDefault();
        var result1 = students.Where(n => String.Equals(n.StudentID, studentID)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.Groupsz.Add(new Student() { StudentID = studentID, FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName });
        }
        if (result1 != null)
        {
            result1.StudentGroup.Add(new Group() { GroupName = group });
        }

    }
```

Comment: that means you haven't found a problem - just a fix :). Your code is real confusing, I think you should take a hint from @phoog, reorganize a bit and then solve it.

Comment: Its just hard when your not very good at this and when it starts to make sense you then find out you could be wrong. Like the above code in my answer, to me it is telling me I am making a duplicate record. But because I have no datasource I cant really find out. This is all just added live.

Comment: You should set up some tests then, imitate the source, 'live' (component) of it - and test your thing on something less live - that is everyday problem for many, you are not the first:).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, your code is somewhat confusing.  As you've no doubt discovered, this can make it more difficult to find errors of logic in the code.

If you have not yet done so, learn how to use the debugger.  Step through the methods that return the students in a group.  Check the values of the variables using the "locals" window, or by hovering over them with the mouse.  You should be able to see, fairly easily, which variables have unexpected values.  Then, of course, the next step is to determine *why* they have unexpected values.  It could be an error in your code, or it could be unexpected data in the database.

Once you've narrowed down the location of the problem, if you still don't understand *why* the problem persists, you should be in a better position to ask a more focused question on stackoverflow.